# How to add a transition to a absolute positioned box on hover

Tags: css

Hi I have created boxes with `overflow: hidden`, now on `hover` I would like for the box to drop down showing inner box.

I have created this and it works fine however I would like to use a transition on this effect to smoothen the drop down. I have added the transition and it is not working.

Any advice would be great on this thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
#items {width:300px;}
.item {width:100px;border:solid 1px #ccc;float:left;height:20px;
 z-index:0;overflow:hidden;position:relative;}

.item:hover{overflow:visible;z-index:100;}
.item:hover .inner{z-index: 100;}
.inner{position: absolute;
 background: white;
width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="items">

<div class="item"><div class="inner">text 1<br>text 1<br>text 1</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="inner">text 2<br>text 2<br>text 2</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="inner">text 3<br>text 3<br>text 3</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="inner">text 4<br>text 4<br>text 4</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="inner">text 5<br>text 5<br>text 5</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="inner">text 6<br>text 6<br>text 6</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="inner">text 7<br>text 7<br>text 7</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="inner">text 8<br>text 8<br>text 8</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="inner">text 9<br>text 9<br>text 9</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="inner">text 10<br>text 10<br>text 10</div></div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/), please?

Comment: hi yes ofcourse http://jsfiddle.net/Lo7xt851/

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery Animations to that:

Your div for id=items should be.

```
<div id=items onmouseover=effects() onmouseout=normal()>

</div>
```

And your javascript should be:

```
<script>
    function effects()
    {
        $(".inner").show();
    }

    function normal()
    {
        $(".inner").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  build the menu you want with just CSS, but you'll need a better html structure. I don't want to rebuild the wheel, so I got one (a very simple one) that is already done:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-smooth-drop-down-menu

HTML

```
 <nav>
        <ul class="cf">
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav ul {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF;
    background: #ddd;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 25%;
}
nav a {
    background: #ddd;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    font: bold 16px/50px sans-serif;
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
nav .dropdown:after {
    content: ' ▶';
}
nav .dropdown:hover:after{
    content:'\25bc'
}
nav li:hover a {
    background: #ccc;
}
nav li ul {
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
nav li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50px;
    visibility: visible;
}
nav li ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
nav li ul a:hover {
    background: #bbb;
}

/* Clearfix */

.cf:after, .cf:before {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}
.cf {
    zoom:1;
}​
```